# Why is subdomain part of calculation pagespeed

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Why is my subdomain having a large effect on my Google PageSpeed?

On my homepage there is a link to my subdomain, which is a client portal. First I used a direct link to https:// clients. mydomain. com but as a test I've created a redirect page as https:// mydomain. com/clients which has the meta tag robots nofollow noindex and the page is redirecting to the subdomain. When I run pagespeed analysis, there is no difference for both options and my site's score is only 40 and mainly because of scripts, css and caching issues of the subdomain. There is no option or need to update any of this.

Is there a way to prevent this? DNS is handled by cloudflare.

Victor

Comment: This will have no bearing at all on Page Speed Insights analysis, a link does not get followed. The only way this could possibly be having any impact on your main site is if you are serving an asset from the subdomain and it is slow. Do you want to share the URL so I can confirm and help identify the actual problem (which could possibly be a DNS issue from what you have said).

Comment: Thanks @GrahamRitchie , txlwebagency.com

Comment: It's used in an iframe so will contribute to the pages content and its speed. You might be able to delay its loading considering it is nod displayed on load.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath well I could have saved myself a load of time investigating (took me nearly 10 minutes to spot the iframe...I blame it being a Saturday for my slowness! ) and answering if I had read your comment first, spot on and +1!

Comment: Thanks @TonyMcCreath!! Never thought about that duh.... Got some work to do ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is not the link in the footer but your call to action / proposal request form.

You contact form is hosted on your sub domain and you load it into an iframe.

As such it is perfectly valid that all of the CSS and JS that would show on that page if you visited directly is also loaded into your main site within the iframe and as such contributes to page load times, total blocking time etc.

The simplest solve would be to remove the iframe from your "request free proposal" modal.

Then when someone clicks on "Request Free Proposal" you would add the iframe via JavaScript.

Obviously that is the quick fix and not the ideal. Ideally you would have the form as part of your main page and submit from there.

Either way the answer is to remove your iframe in the "request free proposal" page and then there will be no assets loaded from your subdomain.

Comment: Thanks Graham! That makes sense. Now have to figure out a way to add prospects to my crm without the iFrame.... Have a great weekend!